# Disable swipe left and right in angular bootstrap corousel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to disable the ng-swipe-right and ng-swipe-left action for angular bootstrap corousel. Here is what I tried:

After the corousel loads:

```
$timeout(function() {
 angular.element('.corousel').attr('ng-swipe-right','');
 angular.element('.corousel').attr('ng-swipe-left','');
}, 10);
```

This does not work, what am I missing

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are doing this but to answer your question

you can try this to remove attribute in `angular.js`.

```
var selectedElement = angular.element( document.querySelector( '.carousel' ) )
selectedElement[0].removeAttribute("ng-swipe-right")
```

**OR**

this to change a particular attribute value

```
var selectedElement = angular.element( document.querySelector( '.carousel' ) )
selectedElement.attributes['ng-swipe-right'].value = "newValue";
```

Hope it helps.